# How to subscribe to changes of only one key of form group in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I have a `userForm` group which has keys `name`, `email` and `phone`. Also I have a `onValueChanged` function which one subscribes to form changes and validate `name`, `email` and `phone`. And `onValueChanged` runs every time, when `name` or `email` or `phone` change but I don't want to validate, for example, `name`, if name doesn't change. What is the right way to solve my problem?

```
 buildForm(): void {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', [
          Validators.required,
        ]
      ],
      'email': [''],
      'phone':    ['', Validators.required]
    });

this.userForm.valueChanges
  .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
```

Comment: What does onValueChanged look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do

```
this.userForm.controls['name'].valueChanges(...)
```